# Unable to Watermark a text box in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form that takes the user name,password & occupation. If the occupation happens to be a student then I create a new box using JavaScript to input the users university email. This works fine & I am also able to watermark the username and password boxes. However when the new university email box shows up i am unable to watermark it. I cant understand why.

```
$('#editfill_occupation').change(function() {
    if ($("#editfill_occupation").val() == "0") {
        $('#editfill_uniemail').watermark("Please enter your university email address ");
        $('#editfill_uniemail').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#editfill_uniemail').hide();
    }
});​
```

My editfill_uniemail is defined like this :

```
<input type="text" name="editfill_uniemail"  id="editfill_uniemail" style="display: none;" >
```

I also tried to make use of the placeholder attribute in the above definition but it does not work . What am i possibly doing wrong ? or is not the write way to watermark ?

Comment: try using `live()` instead of `change()`

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/8FMpu/ :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried an HTML placeholder attribute?

**EDIT:** I see that you have, but my code works correctly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/4nGdQ/

HTML:

```
<select id="editfill_occupation">
    <option value="0">Providing demos for questions</option>
    <option value="1">Just kidding about that</option>
    <option value="2">But next time,</option>
    <option value="3">Please do your own :D</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="editfill_uniemail" placeholder="Please enter your university email address" id="editfill_uniemail" style="display: none;" >​
```

The placeholder attribute is currently supported in [all modern browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) and will be supported in IE 10 (In this case, caniuse.com just doesn't show one in IE)

Don't forget a `document.ready()` handler...

Comment: This is great . I  figured out my mistake . I used placeholder incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Another demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aXzuS/

You can accomplish this by using `.focus` and `.blur` API.

Good link: http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/A-simple-jQuery-watermark-textbox.aspx

Hope it fits the needs! `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tbval = $('#hulk').val();

    $('#hulk').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });

    $('#hulk').blur(function() {
        $(this).val(tbval);
    });

});​
```

Comment: The only problem is that _all_ text will be grey... Hey, didn't think of doing a "box-smiley" that way :D

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the .focus and .blur api's . maybe i shall use them in future !

Comment: @rockstar no worries! Glad it helped. :) + 1 to you anyways.